# Varnishtest (Varnish 5.1.3) - Second server response is not used

Tags: varnish

```
varnishtest "TRACE requests"

server s1 {
       rxreq
       expect req.method == "TRACE"
       expect req.url == "/1"
       txresp

       rxreq
       expect req.url == "/2"
       txresp
} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    import std;

    sub vcl_recv {
        if(req.method == "TRACE") {
            return(synth(405, "Method Not Allowed")); 
        } 
    }

    sub vcl_deliver {
        set resp.http.x-forwarded-for = client.ip;
    }
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -req TRACE -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 405
    expect resp.reason == "Method Not Allowed"

    txreq -url "/2"
    rxresp
    expect resp.http.x-forwarded-for == "127.0.0.1"
} -run
```

The above is one of my varnish tests but the test fails and from the varnishtest output it appears as if it is failing on the expect req.method =="TRACE" statement. However I was under the impression that the first call the client made would be used by the first server  rxreq/txresp block and the second client call would be used by the second server rxreq/txresp block.

```
**   c1    0.4 === txreq -url "/2"
**** c1    0.4 txreq|GET /2 HTTP/1.1\r
**** c1    0.4 txreq|\r
***  s1    0.4 accepted fd 5 127.0.0.1 36789
**   s1    0.4 === rxreq
**** s1    0.4 rxhdr|GET /2 HTTP/1.1\r
**** s1    0.4 rxhdr|X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1\r
**** s1    0.4 rxhdr|Accept-Encoding: gzip\r
**** s1    0.4 rxhdr|X-Varnish: 1003\r
**** s1    0.4 rxhdr|Host: 127.0.0.1\r
**** s1    0.4 rxhdr|\r
**** s1    0.4 rxhdrlen = 104
**** s1    0.4 http[ 0] |GET
**** s1    0.4 http[ 1] |/2
**** s1    0.4 http[ 2] |HTTP/1.1
**** s1    0.4 http[ 3] |X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
**** s1    0.4 http[ 4] |Accept-Encoding: gzip
**** s1    0.4 http[ 5] |X-Varnish: 1003
**** s1    0.4 http[ 6] |Host: 127.0.0.1
**** s1    0.4 bodylen = 0
**   s1    0.4 === expect req.method == "TRACE"
---- s1    0.4 EXPECT req.method (GET) == "TRACE" failed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really know why your above test does not work, even if it looks good.

however i generally test it like this.:

```
varnishtest "TRACE requests"

server s1 {
       rxreq
       txresp
       rxreq
       txresp

} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    import std;

    sub vcl_recv {
        if(req.method == "TRACE") {
            return(synth(405, "Method Not Allowed")); 
        } 
    }

    sub vcl_deliver {
        set resp.http.x-forwarded-for = client.ip;
    }
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq -req TRACE -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 405
    expect resp.reason == "Method Not Allowed"
    expect resp.http.x-forward-for == <undef>


} -run

client c2 {
    txreq -url "/2"
    rxresp
    expect resp.status == 200
    expect resp.http.x-forwarded-for == "127.0.0.1"
} -run
```

this passes, and "only" validates the response, since the request is anyway handmade so the `expect` on input, is not really necasssary.

also splitting it into multiple clients, is a good-practice i think - as a unit-test should only do one thing.